# How to make language choice Required for Taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

Is there any way to make the language choice required for taxonomy term.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to perform this.

Otherwise, how can I at least set a default language choice for my taxonomy.
By exemple, I would like to make English as default language. That's mean when the user will create a term the first time, the language choice will be english.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What modules are you using for the language choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom module and use the following code

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id=='taxonomy_form_term'){
     $form['#after_build'][] = 'MYMODULE_after_build';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
   if($form['language']['#value']=='und'){
     $form['language']['#default_value']='en';
     $form['language']['#value']='en';
   }
   return $form;
```

}

**NOTE: In your custom_module.info file use this `dependencies[] = i18n_taxonomy`, so that your module can only be enabled if internationalization is enabled**

Comment: Thanks a lot wolverine :) please see my other question if you can :)